# Load specific items in second UI Collection View after tap a cell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with different category cell. When tap one of this I'd like to load all recipes with that category.

I have two class:
a. CategoryModel - to manage the category

```
    class CategoryModel: NSObject, NSCoding
{
    var nameCategory: String
    var iconCategory: UIImage
    var recipes = [RecipeModel]()
```

b. RecipeModel

```
    class RecipeModel: NSObject, NSCoding
{
    var nameRecipe: String
    var quantityRecipe: String
    var recipeTime: String
    var preparationTime: String
    var cookingTime: String
    var bakingTempRecipe: String

    var difficultyLevelRecipe: String

    var imageRecipe: UIImage

    var ingredients: [IngredientModel]
    var directions: [DirectionModel]

    var categoryRecipe: String
```

I suppose to insert someone in the CategoryCollViewController when I selected the one of all categories... but I don't know to do it!
Someone help me, please!

RecipeCollViewcontroller

```
    class RecipeCollViewController: UICollectionViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    var category: CategoryModel!
    var recipesList = [RecipeModel]()

    struct Storyboard
    {
        static let leftAndRightPaddings: CGFloat = 2.0
        static let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2.0
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        longPressGesture()

        RecipeDataManager.shared.recipeController = self

        title = category.nameCategory

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        let collectionViewWidth = collectionView?.frame.width
        let itemWidth = (collectionViewWidth! -  Storyboard.leftAndRightPaddings) / Storyboard.numberOfItemsPerRow

        let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: 250)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return category.recipesList.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RecipeCell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeViewCell
        let recipe = category.recipesList[indexPath.item]

        cell.labelNameRecipe.text = recipe.nameRecipe
        cell.imageViewRecipe.image = recipe.imageRecipe
        cell.labelPrepareTime.text = String(recipe.recipeTimeInt)
        cell.labelQuantityFor.text = recipe.quantityRecipe

        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {
        RecipeDataManager.shared.recipes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
```

[image: Collection view show the all category]
[image: Seconc Collection view where I'd like to show the recipes with that category]

Comment: Do you want to populate the screen with title 'breads' after tapping on any category?

Comment: Yes. Show all recipes with var “breads”...

Answer (score 1):

Declare ** recipesList** in the next screen's ViewController.

```
var recipesList = [RecipeModel]()
```

Now in your categoryViewController, implement this CollectionViewDelegate method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc=self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewControllerIdentifier") as? YourViewControllerClass
    recipesList = self.categoryList[indexPath.row].recipes
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

Access your recipes array from ** var recipesList** from declared earlier

Comment: thank you so much for your attention. So, I declare **var reciplesList ** in RecipeCollViewController, when to show the recipes of one category. And in the CategoryCollViewController implement the delegate method that you write up... If I have understand correctly the solution show the follow error: /* Argument passed to call that takes no arguments */ at line ** let vc ** and /* Use of unresolved identifier 'recipesList' */ in the follow line...

Comment: Yes, that would do it.

Comment: Ok, i have fixed the errors... ** categoryRecipe = self.category?.recipes[indexPath.item] ** but now the AppDelegate.swift return an error: /* Thread 1: signal SIGABRT */... when tap one of the category... Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: In the storyboard make sure you set storyboardID for the recipecollviewcontroller. Click on the top left dot on the vc in storyboard and set the value in the left side panel.

Comment: Nothing, your solution crash my app in other points... i need to search other solution... sorry ;(

Comment: For example /* Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value */ in the follow line: 'title = category.nameCategory'. I have try every solution... If remove your code the app run again...

Comment: You are not handling optionals correctly. Anyways I’m here to help. Post code and screenshots by updating the question

Comment: I have try to set optionals... I have update the question, but I don't know exactly what I can help you to understand the problem... Thx